# What does 'Constrviolation' physically mean in Matlab's fmincon output?

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the *fmincon* function in Matlab. I have been trying to figure out what 'constrviolation' means when you run the function and call output. When you get infeasible solution or the solver end prematurely, you get a non-zero (& non-integer) constrviolation.

I put in a screen shot for reference. 
[image]

I have searched the documentation and it says it means "Maximum of constraint functions" and I have no idea what that means. It's not an integer number so my first guess was that it is the percentage of constraints violated (or satisfied).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just interpreting the docs given *some* optimization-background:

> constrviolation
>
> ```
> Maximum of constraint functions
> ```

This is just the maximum of all absolute constraint-function errors

Example:

```
x0 + x1 = 1
x0 + x1 + x2 = 2
```

Somehow the solution is:

```
x = [0.6, 0.5, 0.9]
```

constrviolation is:

```
max( abs( 0.6 + 0.5 - 1 ), abs( 0.6 + 0.5 + 0.9 - 2 ) ) = max( 0.1, 0 ) = 0.1
```

**This is bad and technically means: your solution is infeasible!** (should converge to zero; e.g. 1e-8)

As the solver did not end very gracefully, it can't give you a real status about the problem (feasible vs. infeasible).

It might be valuable to add: Interior-point algorithms (like used here) might (some do, some don't) iterate through infeasible solutions and only finally converge to a feasible one (if existing)!

**Also bad**:

> firstorderopt
>
> ```
>  Measure of first-order optimality
> ```

Should converge to zero too (e.g. 1e-8)! Not achieved in your example!

Now there are many possible reasons why this is happening. As you did not provide any code, we only can guess (and won't be happy about it).

You probably hit some iteration-limit like `MaxFunctionEvaluations` or `MaxIterations`. The ratio of `funcCount` and `iterations` look like numerical-differentiation, which can push the number of functions calls a lot!

Comment: Is the constrviolation looking at both the linear (Aeq, beq, A,b, ub, lb) and nonlinear (c, ceq) constraints or just at one?

Comment: As this is the only output in that regards i see not reason to look at a subset. But i'm going just by the docs too! Expect it to check all constraints (if you set up your opt-problem correctly). **Just check it**. Take your sub-optimal x and input it to your constraints (don't ask how; i'm not much of a matlab-guy)!